# Python Socket [Winerror 10049] On amazon windows instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2

Trying to use a python socket to send images from my local computer to an Amazon ec2 windows instance.

I am using the public IP from the dashboard and running into the error "OSError: [WinError 10049]"
Local computer code:

```
import socket

# You run this second
# This will go on Jetson Nano

# AF_INET = IPv4, SOCK_STREAM = TCP
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect(('EC2 public IP', 1256))

file = open('apple.jpg', 'rb')
image_data = file.read(4096)

while image_data:
    client.send(image_data)
    image_data = file.read(4096)

file.close()
client.close()
```

Amazon EC2 windows code:

```
import socket

# You Run this first
# this will go on EC2 server

# AF_INET = IP, SOCK_STREAM = TCP
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind(('Public Ip value', 1256)) #Im am using public ip from ec2 dashboard
print("Waiting for connection.")
server.listen()

client_socket, client_address = server.accept()

file = open('apple_SENT_5.jpg', "wb")
image_chunk = client_socket.recv(4096)  # stream-based protocol

while image_chunk:
    file.write(image_chunk)
    image_chunk = client_socket.recv(4096)

file.close()
client_socket.close()
```

On my amazon security inbound/outbound rules I have:

[image: inbound]
[image: outbound]

The firewalls are turned off on both devices as well

and the error I am getting from the EC2 server-side is

```
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: Your private IP is only accessible to other EC2 instances.  You need to use the public IP.  Isn't that the one you use when logging in to it?  10049 is EADDRNOTAVAIL.  Are you getting that on the server side?  That would imply there's another app listening on that socket.

Comment: Please write your code as ```Your Code``` so people can test it.

Comment: sorry about that just changed it.  I am now using the public IP from the dashboard and running into the [WINERROR 10049]

Comment: Curious.  If you do `ipconfig`, do you see that IP address on one of the interfaces?  Maybe I'm full of it with my public/private advice.  If they have an external router doing the public->private conversion, then you WOULD need the local IP address.

Comment: Yes, I just checked my own EC2 instance, and it's interface has the private IP address.  My mistake.  The CLIENT will have to use the public address, but the SERVER binds to the private one.

Comment: No I don't, I just see the private IPv4 address not the public one

Comment: Great! that worked, Thank you so much. Just to clarify I used the public IP on my client side and then used the private IP for the server.

Comment: EC2 uses NAT. Your server doesn't know that its own public IP address belongs to it.